# Confusing result trying to set values on Dictionary within class

Tags: f#

I have just started picking up F# as part of a personal project to implement Conways Game of Life in many different languages, and I've run into an issue when trying to set a value on a Dictionary within a class.

```
module World

open System.Collections.Generic

type World() =
  member private this.cells = new Dictionary<string, int>()
  
  member this.add_cell(): int =
    printfn "%A" this.cells
    this.cells.Add("0-0", 123)
    printfn "%A" this.cells
    this.cells["0-0"]

let world = new World()
world.add_cell() |> ignore
```

This gives me the following output:

```
seq []
seq []
Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key '0-0' was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at World.World.add_cell()
```

There are some weird things happening, and I'm not sure why.

1. The this.cells, which should be a dictionary, is outputting as a seq []?
2. Immediately after adding a value to the dictionary, the output of this.cells is still blank
3. When trying to get the dictionary value using a key I just added, it does a runtime exception

Can anyone help me understand why this is the case? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new, fresh, empty dictionary on every access.

You see, the syntax `member this.foo = bar` does not create a memory cell (aka a "variable") in the object. Instead, it creates what's called [a "property"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties), which are generally just a pair of `get` + `set` methods, but in this case there is not even a `set` method, only `get` (aka "read-only property").

Every time you write `this.cells`, that `get` method is called, creates a new dictionary, and returns it. So every line in `add_cell` is really working with a fresh dictionary, just created.

To make it a memory cell (aka a "variable") that holds a reference to the same dictionary the whole time, use `member val` instead:

```
    member val cells = new Dictionary<string, int>()
```

This will create what's called [a "field"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/explicit-fields-the-val-keyword) - a memory cell embedded in the object. It's initialized at object creation and keeps its value, and you can reference it as `this.cells`.

Yes, I know, the syntax is a bit confusing around all these `member`s and stuff. I see it as more of a feature than a bug: it discourages the use of classes.

Alternatively, you can use `let`:

```
    let cells = new Dictionary<string, int>()
```

This will also create a "field" behind the scenes, but there are two differences: (1) the field is "private" - i.e. inaccessible outside of the class itself, and (2) inside the class you access it just by name, without the `this.` qualification.

---

As to why the dictionary prints as `seq []` - well, that's because a dictionary *is* a `seq`. It implements `IEnumerable<_,_>`, which is what sequences in F# are.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. The fact that class members re-evaluate each time they are called was surprising. I’ve not yet come across another language that does that. With this change, I was able to complete my F# implementation, which you’re welcome to view here: https://github.com/KieranP/Game-Of-Life-Implementations/tree/master/f%23

Comment: All .NET languages have computed properties. And many other languages have as well - e.g. JavaScript, Ruby, Python, C++, Swift.